# Use Partition in SQL

Tags: sql-server, database-partitioning

I have a problem with a query. Here is the query.

```
SELECT UserID, MAX(UserName) as UserName, MAX(TransactionTime) as TransactionTime,         MAX(LastAction) as LastAction 
FROM UserActivities 
WHERE OrganizationID = 26465
GROUP BY UserID
```

There are so many records for particular user at different TransactionTime.
I want to take LastAction along with other records.
How can I do it? 
Is SQL partition will work here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A [ranking function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx) is probably what you are looking for:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
   SELECT UserID, UserName, LastAction, row_number() over(partition by UserId order by TransactionTime desc) RowNo
   FROM UserActivities 
   WHERE OrganizationID = 26465
) t
where t.RowNo = 1
```